# データフレームの転置方法

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasのデータフレームで、軸を指定して転置する方法がありましたらご教示いただけませんでしょうか？

具体的には、下記データフレーム（「ID」「year」別に「金額」「個数」を集計したもの）を、

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'year': ['2018', '2019', '2020', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2018', '2019', '2020'],
                   '金額': [3000, 4500, 2000, 1500, 4000, 2500, 1000, 5000, 3500],
                   '個数': [2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3]})
```

下記のように、「id」ごとに　1行のデータフレームに転置したいです。
（「id」ごとに、「year」を軸に、「金額」「個数」を転置するイメージ）

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    '2018_金額': [3000, 1500, 1000],
                    '2019_金額': [4500, 4000, 5000],
                    '2020_金額': [2000, 2500, 3500],
                    '2018_個数': [2, 1, 1],
                    '2019_個数': [3, 2, 5],
                    '2020_個数': [1, 2, 3]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらのページ等を参考に、以下のようにしてみました。
[pandas.DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)
[Reshaping and pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html)
[MultiIndex / advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)
[pandas.DataFrame.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='id', columns='year', values=['金額','個数'])

newcolumns = []
for i in range(len(df2.columns)):
    newcolumns.append(df2.columns[i][1] + '_' + df2.columns[i][0])

df2.columns = newcolumns
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。pivot_tableを使うとよさそう、というところまで、ちょうど考えていたところで、詰まっていました。。
アドバイスいただいたコードを実行してみたところ、下記のようなエラーが出てしまいました。。.appendの部分ですかね・・。kunifさんは、エラーなく実行できましたでしょうか？

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')

Comment: はい、Windows10 2004, 64bit Python 3.8.5, pandas 1.1.1で動作することを確認しています。

Comment: pythonのバージョンが異なったので、アップデートして実行してみたところ、作成したいデータフレームの形になっていることを確認できました！ありがとうございました。